# Combine PDFs and JPGs into one PDF

Tags: windows-7, pdf, printing, jpeg, cutepdf

I have three PDFs and up to 10 JPGs that I need to merge into one PDF. I found PDFSam, but it looks like it doesn't accept JPGs. I'd also like to create a single batch file to do this for me (if that's possible). Since I have CutePDF installed, I can print to PDF, so I thought I might be able to first print all the JPGs to a PDF and then use PDFSam to merge it with the other PDFs. I'm stuck on printing the JPGs through a cmd though. I found this command in the registry

```
> "%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe" "%SystemRoot%\System32\shimgvw.dll",ImageView_PrintTo /pt "%1" "%2" "%3" "%4"
```

Under this key

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jpegfile\shell\open\command
```

I'm not sure what the parameters mean though. Should I even be using that command? If so, how can I pass the PDF printer and all of my JPGs to it? Are there any other/better solutions I might be able to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mogrify to convert pdf to jpg and then combine these with the rest of jpgs:

- http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php

Take a look at this post:

- [http://linuxuser32.wordpress.com/2007/06/16/batch-image-convert-scale-thumbnail-jpegs-pdf/](https://web.archive.org/web/20140903023436/http://linuxuser32.wordpress.com/2007/06/16/batch-image-convert-scale-thumbnail-jpegs-pdf/)

Comment: If not absolutely necessary you may want to avoid the step that involves re-compressing the PDF content.

Comment: Nice, glad it solves your problem!